# datepicker jquery ui and moment datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm using moment datepicker [moment datepicker](http://makingsense.github.io/moment-datepicker/) to display a calendar, I have also in my code, the jquery-ui js file, the calendar works fine until I add the jquery-ui file, the problem is that both javascript files are using a method called $.fn.datepicker, so if I remove the jquery-ui, gets the one on the moment datepicker, but if I add the jquery-ui it uses the one on this. Anybody knows how to force using in my case moment datepicker when both have the same function name declared? I tried to load moment datepicker after jquery-ui but it's always runs the one on jquery

Comment: For sure a quickfix would be to rename the datepicker function in the moment datepicker js

Comment: is there any other way to do it without renaming the touching the file?